# SharePoint Error - Datasheet View refuses to show up!

Tags: sharepoint, view

Recently the DataSheet view of my list refuses to dispaly. I tried numerouse times and with no luck. Other lists works just fine, except for this one.

there is a Java error message on the left bottom corner of the screen that disapears in 2 seconds, then it renders the list in Standard view any time you try it.

I even created a new Datasheet View - the result a Standard View.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MS site regarding the data sheet view and why it may not be available - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909506

Answer (score 0):

The error occured after we installed an add-on to restrict users permissions. It looks like this solution afftects the functionality of the site (we tested it for a few days then disable it). Will wait for an improved solution.

http://www.codeplex.com/SPViewPermission